# Image not getting displayed in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a logo on my web-page. But, it's not getting displayed in the browser. The image is saved in the `Views/Shared` folder. 
I've following code in `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`:

```html
<img src="~/Views/Shared/sabariimg1.jpg" alt="Sample pic" />
```

But, it's not getting displayed in the browser. Instead, following gets rendered:

[image]

Comment: Please post the **rendered** HTML markup. I suspect you have a hardcoded relative path when you should use an app-root-relative path (with the `~` character with ASP.NET's URL Helpers).

Comment: Make sure you provide right url to that image file.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `@Url.Content(String fileName)` to pickup that image file in source folder. Like this:

```html
<img id="img_logo" alt="Logo" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/abc.png")" />
```

Comment: THANKYOU I looked forever for this. src="@myDynamicFilename" doesn't work. The Microsoft documentation says it does, but it doesn't. You have to do Url.Content.

Answer (score 1):

> The image is saved in the `Views/Shared` folder.

1. The folder `Views/Shared` is for view files (.cshtml) and not
   for shared data. You can create a new folder in your root directory
   like `Images` where you save all your images. For logo, better have
   this files structure `Images/Logos` or in Content folder like
   `Content/Images/Logos`. It's not required but a *good practice*!
2. To access a file from any folder you can use the `~` that is the
   absolute path for the root application. This means, to access your
   file image you can just use the following line of code:

```html
<img id="mylogo" src="~/Images/Logos/myimage.jpg" alt="my image logo" class="logo" />
```

I think this should work for any ASP.NET Web-forms or MVC web application.

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake, if that helps anyone in this old question

I had during development without thinking about it changed my code to:

```
<img src="../Images/filename.jpg" />
```

This worked for a while but some views did not load the image

I changed it back to the relative path to root and everything works fine again as it will always find the image through the root path no matter which view causes the reload of the page:

```
<img src="~/Images/filename.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have said your image is in Shared Folder , so the url is not true !! your image should be in *Images/Logos/* Folder.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me. My problem was solved by publishing the Images folder to the server (in VS19, mouse right click on the folder -> Publish)

Answer (score -1):

I had faced the same issue.
I have shared the 'Image' folder in the Server. Now the image is getting displayed. I am not sure how much it helps for but it's more related this problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33404554)